# jMeter - If Controller is only executed if it contains a sampler?

Tags: if-statement, controller, jmeter, sequence

I'm having trouble with the If Controller in jMeter.

I have a thread group. Inside the thread group is a loop controller. Each time the loop executes, it runs an HTTP sampler.

I want to trigger the If Controller based on the response of this sampler.

However, the If Controller only seems to trigger if it contains another sampler.

But I don't want it to contain a sampler. The steps to be executed when it triggers are a JSON Path Extractor and a Beanshell PostProcessor. These are used to extract part of the JSON in the response from the existing sampler and then use this value to update a shared hashmap in the Beanshell PostProcessor. But they won't run without a sampler present inside the If Controller. And if I put a sampler in there, of any description - even a dummy one, the response data from the first sampler is lost and I can't get to the JSON response from it any more - and the test is then broken.

Any idea how to get round it?

I've tried adding blank listeners and things like that but they don't cause the If Controller to trigger. The only thing that does is a sampler which then breaks my test sequence.

An If Controller is not allowed as a child of the first sampler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the jmeter internals work only with samplers. So to run a post-processor in some scope (your IF controller creates the scope), you need a sampler inside it. All the post-processors/timers/listeners etc are actually attached to the samplers of their scope. It is important thing to know about JMeter.

To achieve your goal, you can do a trick where you attach the Regexp extractor to the main sampler and extract all response body to some variable. Then add a dummy sampler and put that variable as the response body. Now you will have the information passed to your extractors within the scope.

Comment: Thanks for that. Seems kind of dumb that it won't trigger without a sampler given that you'll often make decisions based on responses. In the end I used a Beanshell PostProcessor script and a RegEx extractor (within the scope of the original sampler) to achieve the same result and got rid of the If Controller completely.

Comment: Handy to know about faking up a second sampler though. May come in useful at some point.

Comment: Incidentally, the reason it works OK with a RegEx extractor, and not the JSON Path one I was using initially, is that the RegEx extractor handles an empty response (my test gets 200 with body or 304 with no body - depending on what just happened) properly. If you run the JSON Path extractor on a response with no body, it throws a Java exception. The RegEx extractor is obviously better written, as it doesn't. So I can run the RegEx extractor, regardless of the response. I wanted the If Controller to only run the JSON Path extractor on a 200 response.

Comment: Done. I'll take your word for it as I didn't end up using it. But it's a handy snippet for future reference as I mentioned. Thanks again.